# Event Handler for Guard (on exit)?

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

I have a notification system that when guard-rspec fails it lights a LED red, and when it passes, it lights up green, that's all great, but I'm looking for a way to turn the light off if I exit (or guard crashes).

I was wondering if there is a way to catch an *"On Exit"* event and run some code?

Also, is there a way to catch a exception (like an *'on error'* event)?

Comment: i think the guard file is just ruby. did you try adding an at_exit hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use Guard Callbacks

Per https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Create-a-guard, the `#stop` method is called when Guard quits.

The [Callback](https://github.com/guard/guard#callback) section of Guard's readme indicates you can hook into the `#stop` method before or after it runs.  There is no indication that this method will run anything if Guard crashes, so it may only work for clean exits.

Here's an untested example I would start with.

```
# Guardfile

require 'led'

guard :rspec do
    watch('spec/*')

    callback(:stop_end) { set_led(:off) }
end
```

#### Use a Wrapper Script

You could create a ruby script that runs Guard, blocks, and turns off the light once Guard finishes running, even by crashing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# wrapper.rb

require 'led'

system("guard")
set_led(:off)
```

#### phoet's at_exit Suggestion

Assuming whatever crashed Guard doesn't interfere with the `at_exit` callback, this method should work as well as the wrapper script.

```
# Guardfile

require 'led'

at_exit { set_led(:off) }

guard :rspec do
    watch('spec/*')
end
```

I tested this method by running Guard, then in a separate terminal...

```
$ pkill -15 -f guard     # same as Ctrl-c, triggers at_exit
$ pkill -9  -f guard     # kills ruby, does not trigger at_exit
```

Comment: The at_exit works, however when using bundler, it had a slight issue, so to get around it I did:


at_exit do
  Bundler.with_clean_env {
    system "digicolor off"
  }
end